# Ruby on Rails - Adding comments to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

Trying to learn RoR. Currently adding comments to posts by user. So far I have a posts model, comments model and post_comments model (to associate the two). So for in 'rails console' I can run: (say I set p = Post.first and c = Comment.first)

> p.comments << c

This forms an association so it works in the console. I just can't seem to get the comments to form this association from the UI. So far I am creating the comments at "comments/new" (not sure if this is the issue. Do they need to be created on the "show view" for "post").

Here are some code snippets

> Controllers
>   comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @comment = Comment.all
end

def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.new(commentParams)
  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "Comment successfully added"
    redirect_to comments_path(@comment)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

private

  def commentParams
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
  end
end
```

> posts_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :setPost, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy, :sold]
before_action :requireUser, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :requireSameUser, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :sold]

def index
  @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(postParams)
  @post.user = currentUser
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post successfully added."
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  if @post.update(postParams)
    flash[:success] = "Post successfully updated."
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def sold
  @post.toggle(:sold)
  @post.save
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def destroy
  @post.destroy
  flash[:danger] = "Item successfully deleted."
  redirect_to posts_path
end

private
  def postParams
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :price, :description,   category_ids:[])
  end

  def setPost
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def requireSameUser
    if currentUser != @post.user and !currentUser.admin
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit or delete your own items"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

> Models
>   comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_comments
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

> post_comment.rb

```
class PostComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

> post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
  has_many :post_comments
  has_many :comments, through: :post_comments  

  validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 20 }

  validates :description, presence: true,
                      length: { maximum: 1000 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
```

end

> Views
>   posts/show.html.erb

```
  <p>Comments: <%= render @post.comments %></p>
```

This renders the partial below

> comments/_comment.html.erb
>   <%= link_to comment.name, comment_path(comment) %>

Finally is the new comment page as it is.

> comments/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Comment</h1>

<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @comment %>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <%= form_for(@comment, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :comment %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_area :comment, rows: 3, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Please enter a comment", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="center col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly received.

Update

> Log

```
Started GET "/posts/2" for ::1 at 2016-01-15 12:39:55 +0000
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
[1m[36mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE    "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
[1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
[1m[35mCategory Exists (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories"    INNER JOIN "post_categories" ON "categories"."id" =  "post_categories"."category_id" WHERE "post_categories"."post_id" = ?  LIMIT 1  [["post_id", 2]]
[1m[36mCategory Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "post_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "post_categories"."category_id" WHERE "post_categories"."post_id" = ?[0m  [["post_id", 2]]
Rendered categories/_category.html.erb (0.2ms)
[1m[35mComment Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 2]]
Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
[1m[36mCategory Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"[0m
Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 50.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that nowhere in your 'new comment' view you have a reference to the post, so when you create the comment it won't be attached to a post. That said I don't understand why you use the post_comments association table, if a comment belongs to only one post you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes that makes sense to me. Also on the latter observation, would it be best to add a column to the posts db for an array of comments? @taglia

Comment: I would just add a post_id column to your comments table, so comment would belong to posts, and post would have many comments.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go. Does the Post table not already get given an id by default?

Comment: It depends on the migration you used to create it, You can check the file `db/schema.rb` to see exactly how your tables are defined. I will add an answer with a bit more details in a minute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a comment can belong to a single post only, you do not need an association table (post_comments). You just need a simple one-to-many relationship.

Your post comment would be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  ...
end
```

And comment would be like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  ...
end
```

Just make sure that you have the necessary `post_id` column in the `comments` table (you can check the `db/schema.rb` file). If that is missing, you can use the following migration to add it:

```
class AddPostIdToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :comments, :post_id, :integer
    add_index  :comments, :post_id
  end
end
```

You also need to make sure you keep somewhere the reference to the post, whenever a user tries to create a comment to a post. You can add this in a hidden field to your `comments/new.html.erb` template. You could set the hidden field in the `new` action, in PostsController, after passing it through the URL.

So, in your `posts/show.html.erb` template you would have:

```
<%= link_to "Add Comment", new_comment_path(post_id: @post.id) %>
```

In your `new` action, in `PostsController`:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new(post_id: params[:post_id])
end
```

And finally the hidden field in your form would be:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
```

Finally, add the post_id parameter to the list of permitted parameters in `CommentsController`.

Comment: This looks great. I will implement these changes and report back with results. Again much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I have implemented all those changes and it is all set up. The only thing is when I create a new comment and check in console the post_id is set to nil. Not sure how to make it come through all looks correct to me. @taglia

Comment: When you click on the "New Comment" button, does the URL look like `http://your.server.com/comments/new?post_id=123`? Have you added `post_id` to the list of permitted parameters in CommentsController? It should be `params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :post_id)`.

Comment: Yes it looks like that but the "post_id=" has no number on it. I did add to Params also

Comment: Actually just noticed the new page does have the post_id number just never seems to make it to the DB. The posts/show page has this to render the comments "<%= render @post.comments %>".

Comment: So if I understand correctly the post_id is in the URL of the new comment page. If this is the case, and you have the hidden field in the form, look at the log to see if post_id is passed in the params to the create action.

Comment: Yeah you do understand correctly. I will have a look at the logs and see what it states. Again really appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

In your new action, in PostsController:

```
def new
    @comment = Comment.new(post_id: params[:post_id])
end
```

you can use this in the form views

```
<%= form.hidden_field :post_id, value: "#{params[:post_id]}" %>
```